# Capture Log file from multiple scripts

Tags: bash

Im capturing all my script executions via the below command

```
exec > $LOGDIR/myfile.log
exec 2>&1
```

But the problem is my main script contains many other shell scripts(for different functions) which also captures another log in `$LOGDIR/myfile/today.log

If want to capture all the sub script executions also in one log file , say

> $LOGDIR/myfile.log.

My present approach dosesn't capture exection details sub scripts.

Can you please help on this.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean: `exec >> $LOGDIR/myfile.log` ?

Comment: yes, its is exec > $LOGDIR/myfile.log
even if i append , the sub scripts are creating log in different directory.

Bascially i want a single log file to capture everything that the main script and sub script executes

Comment: Create a script in which everything you want to log goes to the screen (stdout), then run the script and catch all the output and redirect it to a file. `./script.sh > stdout.error.log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Nothing you do in a parent script will change the behavior of a child script writing to its own log file.  You'll need to edit the other scripts to use a common log file.

Comment: but this needs to be done inside the script and not outside while executing

Answer (score 2):

If the child scripts are redirecting to file *without* at the same time printing their standard output/error streams you can't really do it in a flexible fashion. The canonical way to do this would be to **ensure that scripts pipe their output to `tee`** so that it can *also* be captured by the parent script.

Answer (score 0):

The logs won't be in a terribly meaningful order, but you could always just [concatenate each log file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2150794) at the end of your script.